# Does Google Search Console tell me the keyword that makes my page show up in the search results?

Tags: google-search-console, keywords, search-analytics, pages

[image]

This tab shows what pages in my site show up in Google Search. Can I know what keywords that are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply click on the "+ NEW" and select "PAGE"

[image]

Then select either "**URLs containing**" either "**Exact URL**" and add the URL you want to look the keywords for.

[image]

Then Simply click on "QUERIES" and it will show all the keywords and their data (clicks/impressions)

[image]

Comment: do you know why there is a mismatch between the `queries` tab and the `pages` tab? See [this gif](https://i.imgur.com/dfzOcqc.gif)

Comment: So the clicks that you see in the PAGES tab are probably coming from you using the URL in google or using the site:www.example.com function which is not reported as a query but will record clicks in the landing page.